# Full height div responsiveness on landscape

Tags: html, css

I'm making a page that has a fixed navigation bar, full-screen background and a text in the middle of it. And I don't know how to make it responsive in landscape modes. On other versions, it behaves properly, but on a landscape, because the height is a lot smaller I assume, the text overlaps with a navigation bar. And it looks really messy.

Is there something I could change in my current code to fix this but to still retain full-screen div? I've looked everywhere, but nothing is really working.

This is my code so far:

```css
.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/1200/600/') no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.headline {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
}

.headline h2 {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #212121;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="hero">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable navbar-light bg-faded fixed-top">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>


  <div class="headline text-center">
    <div>
      <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <br>Morbi in volutpat diam, ut laoreet magna. </h2>
      <a class="btn btn-primary rounded-0" href="#">LINK ONE</a>
      <a class="btn btn-secondary rounded-0" href="#" target="_blank">LINK TWO</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.headline -->
</div>








<div style="height:900px"></div>
```

Comment: You could set the font-size to a relative unit like `font-size: 5vh;` to ensure that the font is always 5% of the viewport height. Although, often the best method is a combination of this *and* [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Comment: Thanks! This helped me! I've used vh + media queries and it's looking a lot better now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can set css by using media query

For Exp :

```
<style  type="text/css">
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { 
/* STYLES GO HERE */
height: 50vh;
}
</style>
```